# how much advantage does a webpack created from scratch give?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I created an application using `create react app`, then I did the `npm run eject` command and I get a list of all dependencies. Yes, I do not have `webpack config` files, which will be if I create my own webpack. I see only one advantage that create react app adds extra dependencies that are not needed. All other settings, as I understand it, I can add the cra application to my own webpack. Can you please tell me why it is so important to create your own webpack? I just don't see much difference between builds. I have read a lot of articles and have not found objectively strong advantages can you tell me